# Оператор pass в объявлении функции python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, операторы

Всем привет. Вопрос, для чего pass объявляют в функции?

```
def print_range(node: Node, l: int, r: int) -> pass
```

Если pass будет стоять в конце функции, получается, что функция вообще никаких данных не выдает? Если так, то почему бы не поставить вместо pass туда другое - None?

В интернете не нашел ответа, хотя может и плохо искал.

Comment: С `None` будет непонятно намеренно оно написано или случайно откуда-то выпало. А `pass` - это прям "пустой оператор", мы так декларируем, что функция ничего не делает, а надо было что-то написать, иначе ошибка будет. Вот и пишем `pass`, это как в ассемблере `NOP` или как её там.

Comment: мы про `-> pass` или, все же, про `: pass` говорим?

Comment: pass не может быть использовано в качестве аннотации, будет ошибка синтаксиса: https://ideone.com/pSZSVb

Comment: Jack_oS я имею в виду -> pass

Comment: @phpstal ошибка синтаксиса, pass- не тип данных

Comment: @Jack_oS, спасибо, теперь стало ясно.